# how to find set of distinct strings from a given string after cyclic shifts?

Tags: c++, string, algorithm, stl

I am solving a [QUESTION][1] in Codeforces where the problem statement asks me to find the set of all distinct strings from a given string after cyclic shifts.
like for example :
Given string :`"abcd"` 
the output should be 4 (`"dabc"`,`"cdab"`, `"bcda"`, `"abcd"`)[note:`"abcd"` is also counted]

So

```
t=s[l-1];

for(i=l-1;i>0;i--)
{
    s[i]=s[i-1];
}

s[0]=t;
```

I applied above method for `length - 1` times for all possible strings but I am unable to find the distinct ones,
is there any STL function to do this?

Comment: `std::set<std::string>` might help.

Comment: Thank you for your response !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use the following:

```
std::set<std::string>
retrieve_unique_rotations(std::string s)
{
    std::set<std::string> res;

    res.insert(s);
    if (s.empty()) {
        return res;
    }
    for (std::size_t i = 0, size = s.size() - 1; i != size; ++i) {
        std::rotate(s.begin(), s.begin() + 1, s.end());
        res.insert(s);
    }
    return res;
}
```

[Demo](http://ideone.com/jI8itB)

Answer (score 2):

Not sure about STL specific functions, however a general solution could be to have all shifted strings in a list. Then you sort the list and then you iterate over the list elements. When the current element is different to the last, increment the counter.

There is probably a solution that is less memory intensive. For short strings this solution should be sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

You can use vector for making a list after rotating by using vector.push_back("string"). Before each push, You can check if it already exists by using something like:

```
if (std::find(vector.begin(), vector.end(), "string") != v.end()) 
{
increment++;
vector.push_back("string");
}
```

Or else you can count the elements in the end by vector.size(); and remove increment++.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you for your response !

Comment: Why use `vector` when a `std::set` or `std::unordered_set` is much more efficient?  Imagine if the string were 1000 characters instead of 6 characters.